# Update a list of entities with corresponding fields equal to an external list

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an entity called *Hazaa* containing two fields: *Killed* (type *DateTime?*) and *Linky* (type *Guid*). The business logic dictates that whenever we create a new instance of *Hazaa*, the old one is supposed to be killed by setting the time stamp.

So, doing it for a single element, I apply the method as follows.

```
public void Create(Hazaa newbie)
{
  using (ModelContainer context = new ModelContainer())
  {
    Hazaa oldie = context.Hazaas
      .Single(hazaa => hazaa.Linky == hazaa.Linky && !hazaa.Killed.HasValue);
    oldie.Killed = DateTime.Now;

    context.Hazaas.AddOrUpdate(oldie);
    context.Hazaas.Add(newbie);

    context.SaveChanges();
  }
}
```

Now, I'd like to use a similar approach for bulk update. The signature of that method would be following.

```
public void Create(List<Hazaa> newbies)
{
  ...
}
```

My problems is that I'm not sure how to perform the selection of pre-existing hazaas given the list of new additions. One way is to apply *foreach* statement and execute them one by one (but that's a slow method). Another one would be to use *Contains* method (but that's a problem because the list might long).

Are there any other options? My colleague suggested the following. I feel that it might be refactored so that it doesn't access *context* so many times. Do I worry without reason, perhaps?

```
public void Create(List<Hazaa> newbies)
{
  ...
  using (ModelContainer context = new ModelContainer())
  {
    List<Hazaa> oldies = newbies.Select(hazaa => context.Hazaas
      .Single(oldie => oldie.Linky == hazaa.Linky && !oldie.Killed.HasValue))
      .ToList();
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you use `Single` I assume that all `Linky`s represent existing records. This means that you can update them without even fetching them from the database first:

```
using (ModelContainer context = new ModelContainer())
{
    foreach(var hazaa in newbies)
    {
        context.Attach(hazaa);
        hazaa.Killed = DateTime.Now; // Will mark hazaa as modified

        context.Add(new Hazaa { Linky = hazaa.Linky };
        context.Hazaas.Add(newbie);
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```